# How to get routeparameter of subroute in Ember

Tags: ember.js, routes

I want to list appointments of persons with an ember app. I have my route defined like:

```
this.resource('person', { path: "person/:personid/" }, function () {
    this.route('appointments', { path: "appointments/:date" });
});
```

Now I have 2 Templates

1. person - Template: show the person's name at the top, then {{outlet}}
2. appointments - Template:  has a backward, date and forward button to navigate through the dates AND also the appointments listed

The Controller of appointments handles the navigation through dates by

```
controller.transitionToRoute("person.appointments",mydatevar)
```

this rerenders also the buttons, because its in the same route. And I don't like that.

I tried different approaches but always when I separate the navigation from the appointment list, I need to deal with the date in two controllers, or routes, somehow.

The navigation needs to know the state of the "subroute"-parameter of the appointments-route. And I think this is totally wrong.

I am confused now :-(

can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways.

```
1. needs: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/
2. send: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_send
```

You can set the date on the appointments controller and use `needs` in order to share data back up to the `person` controller.  Doing so you can have an alias with the appointment date on the person controller.

```
App.PersonController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'appointments',
  date: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.appointments.date') // whatever the date property is
});
```

You can send an action to the parent route informing it that the date has changed.

```
App.PersonRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    dateChanged: function(newDate){
      this.controller.set('date', newDate);
    }
  }
});

App.AppointmentsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   model: function(params){
     this.send('dateChanged', params.date);
     ...
   }
});
```

Comment: this (both) makes absolutely sense! Thx, I currently out of office, i'll check it tomorrow!